# Optimal frequency for penetrating 1 meter of water using radio waves?

Tags: fluid, transmission, radio, radar

We are attempting to penetrate 1m of water featuring dissolved ions ( assume salinity of sea water) using radio waves. Aside for using wavelengths of very low frequency radio or below, what would be the best frequency for achieving this task?

Comment: Which ones have you tested so far?

Comment: `wavelengths of very low frequency` ... wavelength is inversely proportional to frequency

Comment: @SolarMike: We have tried for very low wave frequency ( 10kHz), but the antenna wound up being massive according to our calculations. We are trying to penetrate the water while not needing a massive antenna or an antenna that requires 1MW to use.

Comment: I think that we are going to try for 540 kHz wavelength. This should minimize the attenuation. We are trying to find out how large of an antenna we would need and how much power that would take if we used electrical loading and fractal antenna design for it.

Comment: Radios used to have a long-wavelength reception capability, without requiring a large antenna; a small coil wound around a ferrite rod seems to have been sufficient.

Comment: You may wish to _edit your question_ for clarity -- specifically, is your waterborne application receive only, or do you wish to transmit?  Do you have an idea of how much path loss is acceptable?  I do know that submarine hobbyists were controlling model subs with 72MHz transmitters back in the 1990 -- but I don't know how much reliability they were seeing, nor is there enough detail in your question to know if that information is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underwater radio transmission at *VLF frequencies* has been used for many years by the US Navy to send signals to submerged submarines. Wikipedia has a good article on this which will answer all your questions. Here is a very brief summary:

VLF (10 to 30kHz) signals can penetrate ~tens of meters into seawater, but the wavelengths involved are in the range of 300 to 10 *kilometers* (!!!). Efficient radiation of RF power at those frequencies requires a vertical 1/4-wavelength antenna which is impossibly tall. For this reason, all practical VLF antennas are classed as *electrically short* which means extremely ineffective- which requires them to be driven with huge amounts of transmitter power (~megawatts) in order to produce useful RF signal strengths.

Note that 540 kilohertz is very close to the commercial AM broadcast band and to get seawater penetration will still require *many* megawatts of transmitter power and an antenna hundreds of feet tall.

Note also that you can shorten the required antenna by using the design rules for electrically short antennas but the transmitted radiation effectiveness (also called the *radiation resistance*) is extremely low so you will inevitably run right up against the severe limitations of short antennas.

The *ARRL Antenna Book* (used by ham radio operators) contains most of the design equations for VLF antennas.

Comment: ELF is also used for submarine communication. Both VLF & ELF have the disadvantage that you can't get very much data from the carrier signal.

Comment: That is a very good point about the antenna length. Even with electric shortening, the antenna would still be very large if one wished to not use MW of power. We are not considering using a 1MHz wavelength and electrically shortening it down by about 1/100th such that the antenna length is about 1m. The resolution of the image does not really matter as we are just trying to detect the presence of aluminum at the bottom of a 1m deep pond ( the outcome is binary - either it is detected or it is not detected). What do you think about that?